# Sympy Complex Matrix Inversion/Operations

Tags: python, matrix, complex-numbers, sympy

Using Sympy 0.7.2 from the Continuum Anaconda distribution, (was too lazy to build my own stack, don't hate), I keep running into this problem when doing complex matrix algebra where some of the native functions replace the typical '1j', with an 'I". This is annoying because it does not play well with other arithmetic operations and basically maintains its form and adds on factors instead of computing a condensed result. I'll give an example:

```
>>> T
[          1, 1.0 - 1.0*I]
[1.0 + 1.0*I,           0]
>>> T.inv()
[-(0.5 + 0.5*I)*(1.0 - 1.0*I) + 1, 0.5 - 0.5*I]
[                     0.5 + 0.5*I,        -0.5]
>>> T.inv()*T
[-(0.5 + 0.5*I)*(1.0 - 1.0*I) + 1 + (0.5 - 0.5*I)*(1.0 + 1.0*I), (1.0 - 1.0*I)*(
-(0.5 + 0.5*I)*(1.0 - 1.0*I) + 1)]
[                                                             0,
      (0.5 + 0.5*I)*(1.0 - 1.0*I)]
```

which is clearly retarded beacause T.inv()*T is definitely **1**, (the unit matrix, not the number) and not that mess there, (also the formatting is disgusting..for whatever reason). If I manually replace the "I" with "1j", I get **1**, as you do. The above result is not wrong, (it works out to **1**), but you can imagine that for more complex problems that aren't "lets find the unit matrix", this can get very gross very quickly.

I'm wondering there is a better solution than the one I currently have, which is to convert the matrix to string, and replace the 'I' with '1j' manually....

```
#If A is a complex matrix, Let AI be its inverse.
A_STR = string(A).replace("I", "1j").replace("\n", "")
exec("AI=Matrix("+str(A.shape()).replace("(", "").replace(")", "")+"," + A_STR + ")")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should update to SymPy 0.7.3 (`conda update sympy`).

All you need to do is expand everything. Just call `(T.inv()*T).expand()`. Currently, SymPy does not have a floating point variant of `I` corresponding to `j`, so you will generally have to expand complex numbers manually (SymPy doesn't do the expansion automatically because some people want to leave things factored, though, to be fair, it probably should do the simplification automatically in the matrices, but that is still a work-in-progress).